# Remove duplicate elements by class with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to delete duplicate span.film-date elements using the secondary class. For example I only want to keep the first span with the classes of "film-date Wed29May" and the first span with the classes of "film-date Thur30May".

```
<div class="film-time-list">
<span class="film-date Wed29May">Wed 29 May</span>
<a class="film-tickets" href="#">2.30pm</a>
<span class="film-date Wed29May">Wed 29 May</span>
<a class="film-tickets" href="#">5.20pm</a>
<span class="film-date Thur30May">Thur 30 May</span>
<a class="film-tickets" href="#">2.30pm</a>
<span class="film-date Thur30May">Thur 30 May</span>
<a class="film-tickets" href="#">5.20pm</a>
</div>
```

I thought this would be straight forward enough but as the class that is output dynamically could be any date this snippet won't work which was my initial thought.

```
$('.couldBeAnyClass').not(':first').remove();
```

Any pointers would be great!

My output would be:

```
Wed 29 May 2.30pm 5.20pm
Thur 30 May 2.30pm 5.20pm
```

Comment: Does the text of the `span` elements change too? It would be more reliable to work from that than the class

Comment: Thanks for the update. From your output, are you also wanting to remove the `a` elements containing `5.20pm` in both cases?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The class will always be a copy of the content (date) of the span but without the spaces if that's what you mean. Maybe that will be a better way to check for duplicates, maybe?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No I want to keep all of the times, sorry I've updated my proposed output.

Comment: No problem, I already added an answer for you that does that. Hopefully it works for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve what you require you could loop through the `span` elements checking if the text is the same as the previous element, and if so, remove it:

```js
var prev;
$('.film-time-list span').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text().trim();
  if (prev == text)
    $(this).remove();
  
  prev = text;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="film-time-list">
  <span class="film-date Wed29May">Wed 29 May</span>
  <a class="film-tickets" href="#">2.30pm</a>
  <span class="film-date Wed29May">Wed 29 May</span>
  <a class="film-tickets" href="#">5.20pm</a>
  <span class="film-date Thur30May">Thur 30 May</span>
  <a class="film-tickets" href="#">2.30pm</a>
  <span class="film-date Thur30May">Thur 30 May</span>
  <a class="film-tickets" href="#">5.20pm</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First I would get all elements by the base class. Then I would join the full class of those elements and remove all duplicates.

```js
;window.onload = function(){
  //REM: Looping through all .film-date elements
  for(var tListOfSpans = document.querySelectorAll('.film-date'), i=tListOfSpans.length-1; i>=0; i--){
    var tSelector = '.' + tListOfSpans[i].className.split(' ').join('.');

    //REM: Removing all but the first .film-date plus whatever class elements but the first
    for(var tListOfSelects = document.querySelectorAll(tSelector), j=tListOfSelects.length-1; j>0; j--){
      tListOfSelects[j].parentNode.removeChild(tListOfSelects[j])
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="film-time-list">
  <span class="film-date Wed29May">Wed 29 May</span>
  <a class="film-tickets" href="#">2.30pm</a>
  <span class="film-date Wed29May">Wed 29 May</span>
  <a class="film-tickets" href="#">5.20pm</a>
  <span class="film-date Thur30May">Thur 30 May</span>
  <a class="film-tickets" href="#">2.30pm</a>
  <span class="film-date Thur30May">Thur 30 May</span>
  <a class="film-tickets" href="#">5.20pm</a>
</div>
```

### Edit:

The HTML of the question changed. Hence I changed mine accordingly.

Comment: Prefer this one, since it does not rely on correctly ordered spans.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it! Since the corresponding `anchor` elements are not part of the `span` elements they do not get removed unless they are appended to the element being removed:

```
$(this).append( $(this).next() ).remove();
```

```js
$(function() {
  var prevClass;
  $('span.film-date').each(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    if( index ) {
      if( this.className === prevClass ) {
        $(this).append( $(this).next() ).remove();
      } else {
        prevClass = this.className;
      }
    } else {
      prevClass = this.className;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div class="film-time-list">
  <span class="film-date Wed29May">Wed 29 May</span>
  <a class="film-tickets" href="#">2.30pm</a>
  <span class="film-date Wed29May">Wed 29 May</span>
  <a class="film-tickets" href="#">5.20pm</a>
  <span class="film-date Thur30May">Thur 30 May</span>
  <a class="film-tickets" href="#">2.30pm</a>
  <span class="film-date Thur30May">Thur 30 May</span>
  <a class="film-tickets" href="#">5.20pm</a>
</div>
```

In a case where the span elements are not in order, the following can be used:

```js
$(function() {
  var prevClass = [];
  $('span.film-date').each(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    if( index ) {
      if( $.inArray(this.className, prevClass) !== -1 ) {
        $(this).append( $(this).next() ).remove();
      } else {
        prevClass.push( this.className );
      }
    } else {
      prevClass.push( this.className );
    }
  });
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <div class="film-time-list">
      <span class="film-date Wed29May">Wed 29 May</span>
      <a class="film-tickets" href="#">2.30pm</a>
       <span class="film-date Thur30May">Thur 30 May</span>
      <a class="film-tickets" href="#">2.30pm</a>
     <span class="film-date Wed29May">Wed 29 May</span>
      <a class="film-tickets" href="#">5.20pm</a>
      <span class="film-date Thur30May">Thur 30 May</span>
      <a class="film-tickets" href="#">5.20pm</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a set so it does not have to be ordered. Considering the date is the second class passed to the html element.

```js
const dateSet = new Set();
$(".film-date").each((idx, el) => {
  if(dateSet.has(el.classList[1])) { el.remove(); }
  else { dateSet.add(el.classList[1]); }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="film-time-list">
<span class="film-date Wed29May">Wed 29 May</span>
<a class="film-tickets" href="#">2.30pm</a>
<span class="film-date Wed29May">Wed 29 May</span>
<a class="film-tickets" href="#">5.20pm</a>
<span class="film-date Thur30May">Wed 29 May</span>
<a class="film-tickets" href="#">2.30pm</a>
<span class="film-date Thur30May">Wed 29 May</span>
<a class="film-tickets" href="#">5.20pm</a>
</div>
```